Is learning Aleph-Beis considerd Talmud Torah?
Rema (245:8) codifies the obligation to teach one's child to read the Hebrew Alphabet (Aleph Beis), immediately when the child turns 3 years old.

ומכל מקום מיד שיהיה בן ג׳ שנים שלמות מלמדין אותו אותיות התורה, כדי שירגיל עצמו לקרות בתורה

Is learning/teaching how to read Aleph Beis considered Talmud Torah?
Or is it just a necessary step to be able to read Torah in Hebrew?

Is one mekayem mitzvas talmud torah by reading/learning to read Aleph Beis
Can one teach/learn to read Aleph Beis  in a makom metunaf?
Is it permitted to teach/learn Aleph Beis in front of ervah or tzoah?
Must one recite birchas hatorah before learning/teaching Aleph Beis?


I am not discussing delving into the depths of the hidden secrets contained within Alef Beis, which is obviously Torah study like any other. This question regards the learning to read specifically.

 Looking speceficially for sources that indicate either way. 

If you've ever tried teaching a language to a child by speaking it (the way virtually everyone did for ever and ever) you'll know everything you say is an educational event. The only way to not teach Hebrew in the bathroom (for someone who speaks it, as everyone did way back when) is to not say anything.

I wasn't discussing lashon hakodesh as a language, but the alphabet.

Great Question.
In the Sefer תשובות והנגהחות חלק ד אורח חיים סימן יז he says it is Talmud Torah. Which would means that one cannot teach or learn the aleph beit in a makom metunaf, and one would also not be allowed to teach or learn aleph beit in front of ervah or tzoah.
He seems to have two main points:
The first:

והגר״א שם מביא מקור לדברי הרמ״א מהא דאמרו
במדרש תנחומא בפר׳ קדושים דשלוש שנים ערלי ם
יהיו לכם הכתוב מדבר בתינוק דעד שלוש שנים הוא
כערל ואינו שייך במצוות, ולכאו׳ היינו דוקא בגוף
המצוה שייך לומר כיון שהוא כערל אין שייך במצוה
אבל א׳ ב׳ שהוא רק הכשר ללימוד, שייך אף בפחות
מכן, וע״כ מבואר דעת הרמ״א דס״ל דלימוד אותיות
התורה זהו ג״כ בכלל מצוה דתלמוד תורה, ונכלל
בכלל מה שמתוייבים ללמד בנו מקרא, שבזה ג ם
מלמדו לקרוא

"The Gra there (on the Rema in Yoreah Deah 245:8) brings a source for the words of the Rema from what is said in the Midrash Tanchuma in Parashat Kedoshim, that "שלש שנים יהיה לכם ערלים" refers to a child, that until three years he is like one uncircumcised and is not obligated in mitzvot. And seemingly, this applies specifically to the body of the mitzvah, where it can be said that since he is like one uncircumcised, he is not obligated in the mitzvah. But the learning of the aleph beit, which is merely a preparation for learning, is applicable even before that age. Therefore, it is explained that the opinion of the Rema is that he holds that the study of the aleph beit is also included in the mitzvah of Talmud Torah, and it is included in the general obligation to teach one's son scripture, in which teaching him to read is also included."
The second:

וכן נמי בדין דהלוא ידוע דאותיות התורה אינם
כאותיות של שאר הלשונות, להבדיל, אלא רמוז
בכל אות ואות סודות התורה, וכל נקודה ונקודה יש
בה רמזים לעולמות עליונים, [עיין בגמרא שבת דף
קד. ובב״י בסי׳ ל״ו בצורת האותיות]. והלימוד התור ה
מתחיל בהכרת האות לקריאה ואח״ב מקרא, ולכן
ודאי יש בזה קיום מ״ע דתלמוד תורה, לידע האותיות
לקרוא אותם, שהאותיות גופא קבלנו בלוחות הברית
והם גופא תורה ומקיים בזה המ״ע

"Similarly, it is also the case that it is well known that the letters of the Torah are not like the letters of other languages, but rather every letter of the Torah contains secrets of the Torah, and every dot and point has hints to higher worlds (see Gemara Shabbat 104a and Beit Yosef Siman 36 regarding the shapes of the letters]. Torah learning begins with the recognition of the letters for reading, and afterwards with the scripture. Therefore, it is certain that there is the fulfillment of the positive commandment of Torah study in knowing the letters and reading them, as the letters themselves were received on the Tablets of the Covenant, and they themselves are Torah, and in this, one fulfills the positive commandment."
In קונטרס ובשנה הרבעית חלק ב פרק ב הלכה א עם הערות written by Rav Mordechai Gross he also says its considered talmud Torah and he adds sources to back this up:

ובזוה״ק ח״ג דף עג א מלה קדמאה דאורייתא דיהבין לינוקא אל ף
בית, דא מלה דלא יכלין בני עלמא לאדבקא בסוכלתנו, דלסלקא ליה
ברעותא, וכל שכן למללא בפומהון. וכן דייקו מגמ׳ שבת לא ע״א
ההוא נכרי וכו׳, ועי׳ שד״ח ח״א מערכת א כלל קב משמיה דהשל״ה
דמהאי טעמא אין ללמד עכו״ם אותיות התורה, וכ״כ בברכ״י בשיו״ב
יור״ד סי׳ רמו סק״ד. על כן הנהגה הרצויה היא שאם הבן יודע לומר
ברכות התורה או בעזרת האב, שיאמר הברכות קודם לימוד האותיות. וכן
כשהבן הוא בר הבנה יאמר לו קודם לימודו, שיכוין לקיים מצוות לימוד
התורה.

"In the Zohar (3:73a), the first word of the Torah that is taught to a child is the aleph beit, a word that people cannot grasp with their intellect, to elevate it with intention, and certainly to speak it with their mouths. Similarly, it is inferred from the Gemara Shabbat 31a regarding the story of the non-Jew. The Sdei Chemed (ח״א מערכת א כלל קב) in the name of the Shelah Hakadosh says that for this reason, it is prohibited to teach non-Jews the letters of the Torah. This is also written in Birkei Yosef (בשיו״ב
יור״ד סי׳ רמו סק״ד). Therefore, the proper conduct is that if the child knows how to recite the brachot of the Torah, or with the help of the father, he should recite the brachot before learning the letters."
Sorry for any poor translation and hope this helps!

+1. The wording of the Rema - מלמדין אותו אותיות התורה, כדי שירגיל עצמו לקרות בתורה - implies that it isn't a limmud in it's own rights, but a way of facilitating future Talmud Torah.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64628/759 (Notably, both the authors quoted here are ideologically more likely to want to emphasize the significance of mundane aspects of Hebrew to fight against the modern hebrew revival.)
